# Как заменить картинку, если ее нет в папке uploads на php?

Tags: php

Как можно заменить картинку, если ее нет, ни в базе данных ( поле `image` пустое ) ни в папке с фотографиями `../uploads/` на `php` ?

Php код:

```
<?php  $query_art = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news`");?>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query_art); ++$i): ?>

<?php $array = mysql_fetch_array($query_art); ?>    
<?php $ar_image = $array['image']; ?>

    <?php 
        if (!empty($ar_image)){
            $image = $ar_image;
        } else {
            $image = "none_foto.png";
        }   
    ?>

    <img alt="Фото" src="../uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" class="leftimg" />

  <?php  endfor;  ?>
```

Comment: Сделайте константы в каком-либо классе, которые будут указывать на папку с дефолтными фотками и папку с закаченными фотами.....типа`const UPLOAD_FOLDER = "../uploads/";
const IMAGES_FOLDER = "images";` и дальше просто подставляйте ту константу, в зависимости от случая.......а-ля `$image = (!empty($ar_image)) ? UPLOAD_FOLDER.$ar_image : $image = IMAGES_FOLDER."none_foto.png";` .......в теге `img` будет просто уже `<img alt="Фото" src="<?= $image; ?>" class="leftimg" />`

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Я понимаю что такое константы, но не знаю как это правильно применить, куда это нужно вставить?

Comment: Проверяйте в папке uploads через file_exists

Comment: @fedosov зависит, что у вас за приложение. Если используются классы и то, что выше - это `view`, то в классе нужно сделать константы, которые объявляешь один раз и потом их используешь многократно. В случае с `IMAGES_FOLDER` по хорошему такое нужно хранить вообще в конфиге приложения как `define('ИМЯ_КОНСТАНТЫ', значение)`..и тогда использовать можно просто через имя `echo ИМЯ_КОНСТАНТЫ`.. в классе через `const ИМЯ_КОНСТАНТЫ = значение;` и тогда использование таково: `echo ИмяКласса::ИМЯ_КОНСТАНТЫ;` в вашем коде как использовать я написал. + не забудьте `file_exists` как написал  ilyaplot

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$query_art = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news`");
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query_art)) {
    $imageName = $array['image']; 

    if (!($imageName && file_exists("/uploads/{$imageName}"))){
        $imageName = "none_foto.png";
    }   
?>

    <img alt="Фото" src="../uploads/<?=$imageName?>" class="leftimg" />
<?php
}
```